# Which Plan is better for Blog?

Tags: performance, chat, web-hosting

I am considering these few hosting plans.
Kindly advice which one is better for a blog with Chat?
http://www.webvisions.com/web-hosting

Comment: This is not the palce. Sorry

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a site for asking programming questions only (questions that involve code). Questions that solicits opinions are generally frowned upon here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of those three plans should be sufficient for a blog. However, a chat system might take up an additional database, and these three only provides one database.

You may write-in to request for an additional database should you require an additional one to set-up a chat server. Please contact their sales team directly.

If you wish to ask similar questions in the future, questions like these are more suited to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) or [Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).